# Sobolev Extension on boundary of Lipschitz domain

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

If $\Omega$ is Lipschitz and $f\in C^{0,\alpha}(\partial\Omega)$, then there exists $g\in C^{0,\alpha}(\Omega')$ such that $f=g$ on $\partial\Omega$, where $\Omega\subset\subset\Omega'$.  Is there a corresponding result for $f\in H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)$? In general you can extend $f\in H^1(\Omega)$ to $g\in H^1_0(\Omega')$ with $f=g$ on $\Omega$, but I've never seen anything about how $f$ and $g$ relate on $\partial\Omega$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. To formulate it differently: The image of the trace operator on $H^1(\Omega)$ is $H^{\frac{1}{2}}(\partial \Omega)$ (and of course you can extend Sobolev functions from $\Omega$ to $\Omega'$). More generally, the image of the trace operator on $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ is $W^{1-\frac{1}{p},p}(\partial \Omega)$.

Source: E.g., Demengel, Demengel, "Functional Spaces for the Theory of Elliptic Partial Differential Equations", Chapter 3.

I am not precisely sure how much boundary regularity is required. The source above uses $C^1$ but I am sure Lipschitz is fine.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question: if $f\in W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ with $f=0$ a.e. in $\Omega$, is it necessarily true that $f\in W^{k,p}_0(\Omega)$?

Comment: I don't understand. Are some of the $\Omega$ actually $\Omega'$ or $\partial \Omega$?